# Determinant of $3 \times 3$ block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

When I searched some properties of the determinant of block matrices, most results considered a $2 \times 2$ case. Let $A, B, C$ be $n \times n$ matrices and $I$ be an identity matrix of dimension $n$, and let $X$ be defined as follows

$$\begin{pmatrix}
A & 0 & 0 \\ 
B & I & 0 \\
C & D & I
\end{pmatrix}$$

Assume that $A$ is invertible. Then, what is $\det (X)$?

Comment: Factor that matrix in a suitable way.

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix $M$ is block lower triangular. For such matrices, the determinant is given by the product of the determinants of the blocks on the diagonal so $\det M = \det A \det I_n \det I_n = \det A$. You can prove this directly using the definition of the determinant as a sum of products over permutations. The only permutations that result in a non-zero summand must send $\{ 1, \dots, n \}$ to $\{ 1, \dots, n \}$ and then $\{ n + 1, \dots, 2n \}$ to $ \{ n + 1, \dots, 2n \}$ and similarly $\{ 2n + 1, \dots, 3n\}$ to $\{ 2n + 1, \dots, 3n \}$. By expanding the definition, you'll see that this shows that $\det M = \det A \det I_n \det I_n = \det A$.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I confused you. The matrix is changed

Comment: I understand what you want to say. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Just open the determinant using first row. You will see that $B,C$ and $D$ do not contribute to $\det X$.

Comment: Is the determinant same as $\det A$?

Comment: Alternatively: use column operations to use the lower right $I$ to clear out $C$ and $D$, and then the middle $I$ to clear out $B$...

Comment: @PiggyJin Yes, definitely.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: expand the determinant through last column then you come up a $2 \times 2$ block matrix. Note that in last column all entries are zero except last one which is $1$.

but in first row you have many entries coming from$A$